# Floating footer menu with floating sub-menus

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a floating footer menu using JavaScript and HTML & CSS with other-sub menus for elements in the footer menu. The sub-menus also should float on mouse hoover. Is there any way i can fulfill these needs. Please help and Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're fairly new to CSS (no offence if you're not!)

To make it easier, I'd suggest using the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) framework - it'll save you a lot of time if you're new to CSS and save you from many common pitfalls.

Bootstrap has a [Navbar](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar) component, which you can be fixed to the bottom of the site.  I've attached some sample code, but I'd strongly recommend visiting the Bootstrap website and learning your way around - it'll be well worth your effort.

**HTML (make sure you include the bootstrap stylesheet and javascript)**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <button data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar" type="button">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="./index.html" class="brand">Submenu Example</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="">
            <a href="./base-css.html">Normal Item</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">
              Dropup Item
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```